# How do I get a reference for the current class object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt

In Python, how do I get a reference to the current class object within a class statement?  Example:

```
def setup_class_members(cls, prefix):
    setattr(cls, prefix+"_var1", "hello")
    setattr(cls, prefix+"_var2", "goodbye")

class myclass(object):
    setup_class_members(cls, "coffee")  # How to get "cls"?

    def mytest(self):
        print(self.coffee_var1)
        print(self.coffee_var2)

x = myclass()
x.mytest()

>>> hello
>>> goodbye
```

Alternatives that I've written off are:

1. Use `locals()`: This gives a dict in a class statement that can be written to.  This seems to work for classes, however the documentation tells you not to do this. (I might be tempted to go with this alternative if someone can assure me that this will continue to work for some time.)
2. Add members to the class object after the `class` statement:  My actual application is to derive a PyQt4 `QWidget` class with dynamically created `pyqtProperty` class attributes.  `QWidget` is unusual in that it has a custom metaclass.  Very roughly, the metaclass compiles a list of `pyqtProperties` and stores it as additional member.  For this reason, properties that are added to the class after creation have no effect.  An example to clear this up:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui


# works
class MyWidget1(QtGui.QWidget):
    myproperty = QtCore.pyqtProperty(int)


# doesn't work because QWidget's metaclass doesn't get to "compile" myproperty
class MyWidget2(QtGui.QWidget):
    pass
MyWidget2.myproperty = QtCore.pyqtProperty(int)
```

Please note that the above will work for most programming cases; my case just happens to be one of those unusual corner cases.

Comment: mouad's answer is definitely the one to go with, but to describe what's happening: The class definition is just executing a series of statements within it's own local scope. Once that finishes, the class name, the list of base classes, and the resulting locals dict are passed to the [type constructor](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#type) as `type(class_name, bases_tuple, locals_dict)` which then returns `cls`. Thus, `cls` isn't available at the point you want, only afterwards. Also, using a metaclass will cause it to be called in place of `type`, and with the same signature.

Comment: I didn't know about that `locals()` trick working in classes. Interesting bit of trivia.  :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK there is two way to do what you want:

1. Using [metaclass](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation), this will create your two variables in class creation time (which i think is what you want):

   ```
   class Meta(type):
       def __new__(mcs, name, bases, attr):
           prefix = attr.get("prefix")
           if prefix:
               attr[prefix+"_var1"] = "hello"
               attr[prefix+"_var2"] = "goodbye"

           return type.__new__(mcs, name, bases, attr)

   class myclass(object):
       __metaclass__ = Meta
       prefix = "coffee"

       def mytest(self):
           print(self.coffee_var1)
           print(self.coffee_var2)
   ```
2. Create your two class variable in instantiation time:

   class myclass(object):
        prefix = "coffee"

   ```
    def __init__(self):     
        setattr(self.__class__, self.prefix+"_var1", "hello")
        setattr(self.__class__, self.prefix+"_var2", "goodbye")

    def mytest(self):
        print(self.coffee_var1)
        print(self.coffee_var2)
   ```

N.B: I'm not sure what you want to achieve because if you want  to create dynamic variables depending on the `prefix` variable why are you accessing like you do in your `mytest` method ?! i hope it was just an example.

Comment: Yes, example is silly.  This solution looks very promising.  I failed to mention I am using Python 3 which appears to have different metaclass support.  Working out the differences now...

Answer (score 4):

For Python 3, the class must be declared as

```
class myclass(object, metaclass = Meta):
   prefix = "coffee"
   ...
```

A few other points:

- The metaclass may be a callable, not just a class (Python 2&3)
- If the base class of your class already has a non-standard metaclass, you have to make sure you call it's `__init__()` and `__new__()` methods instead of type's.
- The class statement accepts keyword parameters that are passed on to the metaclass (Python 3 only)

A rewrite of mouad's solution in Python 3 using all of the above is...

```
def MetaFun(name, bases, attr, prefix=None):
    if prefix:
        attr[prefix+"_var1"] = "hello"
        attr[prefix+"_var2"] = "goodbye"

    return object.__class__(name, bases, attr)

class myclass(object, metaclass = MetaFun, prefix="coffee"):
    def mytest(self):
        print(self.coffee_var1)
        print(self.coffee_var2)
```

Comment: +1, for porting my initial answer to python 3, and for teaching me that metaclasses can be any callable (which i didn't know), by the way what should we call them `metaclass function` or `metafunction` ;-), beside this i have some remarks (questions) if i may: 1. If you are writing for python 3 you don't need to inherit explicitly from `object` just `class myclass(metaclass=MetaFun, prefix="coffee")` 2. why are you calling `object.__class__` instead of `type(...)` it's the same of course but i will prefer the latest just wondering :)

Comment: @mouad:  1. You are correct, I could have elided `object` as the base class.   2. In my actual application, the base class (`PyQt4.QtGui.QWidget`) had a metaclass that was *not* `type`, giving me an error when I used `type`.  By using `object.__class__` I'm illustrating how to retrieve the actual base metaclass.

Answer (score 2):

Two more approaches you might use:

A class decorator.

```
def setup_class_members(prefix):

    def decorator(cls):
        setattr(cls, prefix+"_var1", "hello")
        setattr(cls, prefix+"_var2", "goodbye")
        return cls

    return decorator

@setup_class_members("coffee")
class myclass(object):
    # ... etc
```

Especially if you need to add attributes in various combinations, the decorator approach is nice because it does not have any effect on inheritance.

If you are dealing with a small set of of attributes that you wish to combine in various ways, you can use mixin classes. A mixin class is a regular class, it's just intended to "mix in" various attributes to some other class.

```
class coffee_mixin(object):
    coffee_var1 = "hello"
    coffee_var2 = "goodbye"

class tea_mixin(object):
    tea_var1 = "good morning old bean"
    tea_var2 = "pip pip cheerio"

class myclass(coffee_mixin, tea_mixin):
    # ... etc
```

Comment: +1, For the decorator approach , why i didn't think about it :)

Answer (score 1):

See [`zope.interface.declarations._implements`](http://svn.zope.org/zope.interface/trunk/src/zope/interface/declarations.py?view=auto) for an example of doing this kind of magic.  Just be warned that it's a serious maintainability and portability risk.